# Nuclear physics questions

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

Why the mass of nuclues is smaller than the individual mass of nucleon which is the mass of individual subatomic particle? Why is there a missing energy?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32699/2451 and links therein.

Comment: There is no missing energy. The difference between the mass of the nucleus and the mass of the individual separate nucleons is accounted for by the binding energy, which is the energy stored in the strong nuclear force which keeps the nucleons bound together in the nucleus. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy for more details.